# Problem related Dates

Tags: c#

I have Start Date and End Date .I need to calculate how many quarters are there and also the if i have 2 quarters i need to show from which date to which date the 1st quater and also the same for 2nd quarter using C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, firstly you'll need to define *exactly* what you mean by a quarter. Do your quarters always start and end on the same dates, or do they depend on the year, for example?

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this I guess?

```
DateTime curDt = startDate;
while(curDt <= endDate)
{
   //curDt is the curent quarter
   curDt = curDt.AddMonth(3);//if you define quarter as 3 monthes
}
```